# Gwtbootstrap3. Using bootstrap component only with java code- without ui-binder

Tags: java, gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3, uibinder, gwtbootstrap3

Is there possibile to use bootstrap3 elements (from [gwtboostrap3 library](https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#home)) without using ui binder, but using java code like it is done with gwt regular widgets?

I could not find a word about it in Documentation.

F.E. Lets take [button widget](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html) from gwt:

```
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Make a new button that does something when you click it.
    Button b = new Button("Jump!", new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.alert("How high?");
      }
    });

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get().add(b);
  }
}
```

Which will create:

```
<button type="button" class="gwt-Button">Jump!</button>
```

In gwtbootstrap3 I have to do something like that:

```
<b:Button type="DEFAULT"/>
```

Please help me with that.

Is it possible to use gwtbootstrap3 library components like button with pure java instead of uibinder xml files?

Is there solution that works out of box?

Or maybe I should write my own classess that extends native gwt widget an add bootstrap releated css classes?

Comment: Are you having any trouble with `new org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Button("Jump!")`?

Comment: No. I didn't know that I can create gwtbootstrap3 widget that way. There is no word about it in demo page. Thanks. You saved my day. Please create answer cause it solve my problem. I would like to close it. Thanks once again.

Comment: Nil sweat, glad I helped. There is no word about it because it's implicit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes!

You can use the widget as you please, refer to the their [javadoc](https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/apidocs/index.html) to see what constructors they have! They are a different set of widgets and might not be analogue of GWT standard widgets.

### Bonus

GWT UiBinder does no different than you, all it does is reduce the boilerplate, generating java classes that automate the instantiate of the widgets. You can add the compiler option `-gen` to see these transient classes. Usually , they are deleted after GWT compiles your application, as they are no longer needed. Take a look the the [compiler documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions) for more info!

Comment: UiBinder have one disadvantage. When You use it You are obligated to use  strings in your code, which are validated at runtime, not in compile time, there is no IDE intelisense to help with them. This is why I dont like them at all. But once again thanks for Your help.

Comment: What else you use instead a string? I think IntelliJ has support for auto completion inside a ui.xml file. Here is this 5 years old blog post that demonstrate some validation too http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/01/gwt-uibinder-support/

Comment: Unfortunatelly in my Eclipse it looks like that: http://picpaste.com/pics/0fWxbDuO.1435175156.png

Comment: Ah, you're missing the imports, and there is a mistake at this ui.xml. Add the import to the widget first, see here how they do it: https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gwtbootstrap3/demo/client/application/components/ButtonDropdownView.ui.xml Notice these xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui" at the top of the XML, you're missing that. And then the uiBinder can have only one root element. Remove that <div> declaration there and leave only the <b:Dropdown>

Comment: I still prefer Java code. It is everything oop. Much easier to refactor project :D